# Editing Multiple files in vi with Wildcards

Tags: unix, shell, vi, wildcard

When using the programmers text editor vi, I'll often use a wildcard search to be lazy about the file I want to edit

```
vi ThisIsAReallLongFi*.txt
```

When this matches a single file it works great.  However, if it matches multiple files vi does something weird.

First, it opens the first file for editing

Second, when I :wq out of the file, I get a message the bottom of the terminal that looks like this

```
E173: 4 more files to edit
Hit ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I hit enter, **it returns me to edit mode in the file I was just in**.  The behavior I'd expect here would be that vi would move on to the next file to edit.

So,

1. What's the logic behind vi's behavior here
2. Is there a way to move on and edit the next file that's been matched?

And yes, I know about tab completion, this question is based on curiosity and wanting to understand the shell better.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

vi supports having multiple files available for editing. `:n` goes to the next file, `:N` goes to the previous. Use `:h arglist` for more information.

Answer (score 10):

ANSWER TO CURRENT QUESTION

You may write: `vim -p myfile*` and vim will open all the matches for `myfile*` in the current directory into multiple tabs. Then, you can edit all files one by one. Navigate using `gt` for going to the next tab and `gT` for going to the previous tab. For saving and quiting all the files in a single go, just write `:wqa` inside vim.

ANSWER TO A SIMILAR PROBLEM

I was facing a similar problem. I had a file named "myfile*" inside multiple subdirectories of my current directory. I wanted to edit a small change in all of them without getting to open them one by one. So, in the command line, I wrote this :

```
$find . -type f -name "myfile*" -exec vim -f {} \;
```

This way, find runs vim for each file. As soon as I quit an instance of vim, find automatically runs another with the next file until all of them have been done. Although, I agree that it would have been better if all the files could have been opened as tabs.

Comment: Additionally, as the max number of open tabs is **10**, it can be convenient to increase the limit by setting a custom `tabpagemax` in your `~/.vimrc`. See [link](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442422-vim-tips-using-tabs)

Comment: +1 for showing how to search within subdirectories and for showing `-exec` paramter for `find`. BTW what is trailing `\;` for?

Comment: // , @Abhinav, thanks for the best response. This deserves more votes.

Comment: @DimitryK 4 years late, but the `\;` is to mark the end of the command for `-exec`, since you can pass multiple args to the command, and then `find` options after. The \ is just to escape the semicolon, you could also do e.g. `find . -exec foo bar {} baz ';' -type f`